# Use XSLT 1.0 to group XML elements into buckets, in order, based on some criteria

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, grouping, bucket

Say I had some XML that I wanted to convert to HTML. The XML is divided into ordered sections:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <section attr="someCriteria">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <p>paragraph 1-1</p>
    <p>paragraph 1-2</p>
  </section>
  <section attr="someOtherCriteria">
    <h3>Subtitle 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>list item 2-1</li>
      <li>list item 2-2</li>
      <li>list item 2-3</li>
      <li>list item 2-4</li>
    </ul>
  </section>
  <section attr="anotherSetOfCriteria">
    <warning>
      Warning: This product could kill you
    </warning>
  </section>
  <section attr="evenMoreCriteria">
    <disclaimer>
      You were warned
    </disclaimer>
  </section>
  <section attr="criteriaSupreme">
    <p>Copyright 1999-2011</p>
  </section>
</root>
```

I have several of these XML documents. 
I need to group and transform these sections based on criteria. There will be two different kinds of buckets.

- So the first section will go in a
  bucket (e.g.`<div
  class="FormatOne"></div>`)
- If the
  second section meets the criteria to
  qualify for the "FormatOne" bucket it
  will also go in this bucket
- If the
  third section requires a different
  bucket (e.g.`<div
  class="FormatTwo"></div>`) then a new
  bucket is created and section
  contents are placed in this bucket
- If the bucket for the fourth section requires "FormatOne" (which is different than the previous format) then a new
  bucket is created again and section
  contents are placed in this bucket
- etc. Each section would go into the same bucket as the previous section if they are the same format. If not, a new bucket is created.

So for each document, depending on the logic for separating buckets, the document may end up like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="FormatOne">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <p>paragraph 1-1</p>
    <p>paragraph 1-2</p>
    <h3>Subtitle 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>list item 2-1</li>
      <li>list item 2-2</li>
      <li>list item 2-3</li>
      <li>list item 2-4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="FormatTwo">
    <span class="warningText">
      Warning: This product could kill you
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="FormatOne">
    <span class="disclaimerText"> You were warned</span>
    <p class="copyright">Copyright 1999-2011</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

this:

```
<body>
  <div class="FormatOne">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <p>paragraph 1-1</p>
    <p>paragraph 1-2</p>
    <h3>Subtitle 2</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="FormatTwo">
    <ul>
      <li>list item 2-1</li>
      <li>list item 2-2</li>
      <li>list item 2-3</li>
      <li>list item 2-4</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="FormatOne">
    <span class="warningText">
      Warning: This product could kill you
    </span>
    <span class="disclaimerText"> You were warned</span>
    <p class="copyright">Copyright 1999-2011</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

or even this:

```
<body>
  <div class="FormatOne">
    <h1>Title 1</h1>
    <p>paragraph 1-1</p>
    <p>paragraph 1-2</p>
    <h3>Subtitle 2</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>list item 2-1</li>
      <li>list item 2-2</li>
      <li>list item 2-3</li>
      <li>list item 2-4</li>
    </ul>
    <span class="warningText">
      Warning: This product could kill you
    </span>
    <span class="disclaimerText"> You were warned</span>
    <p class="copyright">Copyright 1999-2011</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

depending on how the sections are defined.

Is there a way to use an XSLT to perform this type of grouping magic?

Any help would be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with a solution that involves hitting each section sequentially. The processing of each section is broken into two parts: a "shell" and a "contents" portion.  The "shell" is responsible for rendering the `<div class="FormatOne">...</div>` bits, and the "contents" is responsible for rendering the actual contents of the current section **and all following sections until a non-matching section is found**.

When a non-matching section is found, control reverts to the "shell" template for that section.

This gives an interesting bit of flexibility: the "shell" templates may be very aggressive in what they match, and the "contents" sections may be more discerning.  Specifically, with your first example output, you need the `warning` element to appear as `<span class="warningText">...</span>`, and this is accomplished with a more closely matching template.

All "content" templates, after rendering the contents of their current section, call a named template that looks for the "next" appropriate content section.  This helps consolidate the rules for determining what qualifies as a "matching" section.

[You can see a working example here](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm?state=U).

Here is my code, built to replicate what you asked for in your first example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/root/section[1]" mode="shell" />
        </body>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section[
        @attr = 'someCriteria' or
        @attr = 'someOtherCriteria' or
        @attr = 'evenMoreCriteria' or
        @attr = 'criteriaSupreme']" mode="shell">

        <div class="FormatOne">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="contents" />
        </div>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::section[
            @attr != 'someCritera' and
            @attr != 'someOtherCriteria' and
            @attr != 'evenMoreCriteria' and
            @attr != 'criteriaSupreme'][1]" mode="shell" />

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="nextFormatOne">
        <xsl:variable name="next" select="following-sibling::section[1]" />
        <xsl:if test="$next[
            @attr = 'someCriteria' or
            @attr = 'someOtherCriteria' or
            @attr = 'evenMoreCriteria' or
            @attr = 'criteriaSupreme']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$next" mode="contents" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section[
        @attr = 'someCriteria' or
        @attr = 'someOtherCriteria']" mode="contents">

        <xsl:copy-of select="*" />

        <xsl:call-template name="nextFormatOne" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section[@attr = 'evenMoreCriteria']" mode="contents">
        <span class="disclaimerText">
            <xsl:value-of select="disclaimer" />
        </span>

        <xsl:call-template name="nextFormatOne" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section[@attr = 'criteriaSupreme']" mode="contents">
        <p class="copyright">
            <xsl:value-of select="p" />
        </p>

        <xsl:call-template name="nextFormatOne" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="section[@attr = 'anotherSetOfCriteria']" mode="shell">
        <div class="FormatTwo">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="contents" />
        </div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="
            following-sibling::section[@attr != 'anotherSetOfCriteria'][1]"
            mode="shell" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="nextFormatTwo">
        <xsl:variable name="next" select="following-sibling::section[1]" />
        <xsl:if test="$next[@attr = 'anotherSetOfCriteria']">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$next" mode="contents" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template
        match="section[@attr = 'anotherSetOfCriteria']"
        mode="contents">

        <span class="warningText">
            <xsl:value-of select="warning" />
        </span>

        <xsl:call-template name="nextFormatTwo" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

"Each section would go into the same bucket as the previous section if they are the same format. If not, a new bucket is created."

What you have described is essentially the task performed by the instruction

```
<xsl:for-each-group group-adjacent="....">
```

in XSLT 2.0. This assumes that you can write a function which translates your "criteria" into a bucket-name, and call this function within the group-adjacent attribute.

So, how hard a constraint is it that you need to use XSLT 1.0?

If you are stuck with 1.0, then you'll have to go with the sibling-recursion design pattern as proposed by Chris Nielsen.

Comment: Thanks for this, @Michael! We are in a Microsoft shop, and, unfortunately, MS doesn't support XSLT 2.0 (and probably never will). Plus we haven't been able to implement something like [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `template`, `if`, `choose` and `for-each`:

- http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_templates.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_if.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_choose.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp

These (as well as other XSLT elments) will allow you to make conditional behavior to switch between different transform logic.